# Public static string injection on android?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm using public static strings for keeping values into my apk.
Example in my Class:

```
public class Login
{
public static string UserName;
}
```

In my activity:

```
Login.UserName="SomeText"
```

For Some reason which i dont know, all public static strings has been reseted suddenly.(All values has returned on null)
Is there possibility for injection in my code? 'Or' android applications can create a problem like this??

Comment: What sort of injection? Are you accessing this property value even before assigning a value to it?

Comment: No this property takes value just one time in my apllication.Only when user making a login.

Comment: What if user login, then kill the app and reopen the app? He will login every time? You need to put some code to demonstrate/reproduce your problem.

Comment: What do you mean kill the app?You mean closing my apk with Application.Close?Or you mean if user will press HomeButton?

Comment: You could use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

All static variables will be reset and equal to null when you close the application. If you want persistent data then look into android preferences.